# Error using Physics2D.Raycast - optional arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optional-parameters, raycasting

Hello :) I'm using the Physics2D.Raycast method and according to Unity Documentation its input arguments are defined as follows:

```
public static RaycastHit2D Raycast(Vector2 origin, Vector2 direction, float distance = Mathf.Infinity, 

int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, float minDepth = -Mathf.Infinity, float maxDepth = Mathf.Infinity);
```

And I called this method and inserted the following input arguments:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position,
newVelocity, layerMask: hitLayerMask);
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Physics2D.Raycast(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2, float)' 

does not contain a parameter named layerMask
```

Could you help me solve this problem? I don't get why the compiler thinks I'm overloading a method with only three input arguments.

P.S: I'm aware of my introduction of 'transform.position',  a Vector3 object, in a function that supposedly takes in a Vector2 object. But I have done that before and I got no errors. The only novel approach I'm taking is the specification of the argument layerMask :/

I would be grateful for any help.

Edit: Just to clarify, transform.position is a Vector3 object, newVelocity is a Vector2 and hitLayerMask is an integer.

Edit 2: Note that I neglected passing the "distance" input argument because it has a default value Mathf.Infinity. On this webpage about optional arguments (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), on the ExampleMethod() part, it shows how arguments with default values can be neglected. And that is the reason why I neglected the "distance" argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass in distance before layer mask but you failed to do so. The signature of the function is vector2,vector2,float int and others but the current code you have is vector2,vector2,int (hitLayerMask)....

```
    int hitLayerMask = 0;
    int layerMask = 6;
    float distance = 60f;

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position,
        newVelocity, distance, layerMask: hitLayerMask);
```

This will compile but may not work well due to how you are passing in layer. You use bitwise operation to do that.For example, `1<<hitLayerMask`, `1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Environment")`. For more information about layer bitwise operation visit [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html).

Below is the right way of doing this:

```
    Vector3 newVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    float distance = 100f;
    int layerMask = 1 << 6; //cast rays only against colliders in layer 6.
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position,
        newVelocity, distance, layerMask);
```

**EDIT**:

Error is likely there because the feature you are trying to use is not available in the current Unity C# version. Optional parameters and named arguments were added in C# V4 while Unity uses version C#<=3.5 with some features stripped out.

Comment: Oh okay. I thought one could neglect the arguments which had a default value. But I don't have a distance to specify... :s Should I use Mathf.Infinity, as it is the default value?

Comment: Also, this webpage about optional arguments https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx explains how you supposedly can neglect arguments which have a default value, like the distance input argument in the raycast function (Check ExampleMethod() on that page). So not passing distance should work :/

Comment: @Dayman75 you read that page wrong. You can ignore optional arguments from right to left but not from left to right. So, you can neglect **layerMask** but then use **distance**. Although you can't neglect **distance** and use  **layerMask**. For the distance you can use  **Mathf.Infinity** for now until you come up with your own distance. This is different for every game.

Comment: Sorry for my insistence. It's true that "If the caller provides an argument for any one of a succession of optional parameters, it must provide arguments for all preceding optional parameters" (from the website). "However, if you know the name of the third parameter, you can use a named argument to accomplish the task."

So, "anExample.ExampleMethod(3, optionalint: 4);" works.

So, if I'm using layerMask as a named argument, I don't understand why it doesn't work. I'm sorry for being insistent

Comment: My second code clearly mentions that you should forget about named argument and use the bitwise to pass in the layer mask. I even provided a link to learn more about layers and bitwise. Bitwise is how you add/remove layers in raycast. Focus on that. Finally, what you are trying to do is not working because Unity uses C# 2->3.4 but what you want is a feature introduced in C# 4. So it won't work until Unity updates  to C# 4 or more which will happen at the end of this year. So use what everyone else is currently using. If this solved your error, you can accept it as the answer. Happy coding!

Comment: Ah! Okay :) I didn't know Unity uses C# 2->3.4. Thank you.

I don't know why you're bringing up bitwise operations for the layerMask. I'm perfectly aware of what a bitwise operation is and its implications :/ Actually, I passed the layerMask using bitwise operations. I don't think they have anything to do with the question topic, at all. But I thank you for enlightment on the C# "version" of Unity. Thank you for your time helping me.

Comment: My bad. The code in your question did not include the bitwise stuff and it had `layerMask: hitLayerMask`. So I thought you are a beginner because of that...Glad you know what you are doing.

Comment: No problem :) I won't leave your answer as accepted, but if you edit it to address specifically the "C# version" problem that you mentioned I'll accept you answer friend. Otherwise I'll just answer it myself. Once again thank you and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

As the user @Programmer stated, Unity's uses C#2->3.5. I actually searched for the c# "version" using "Debug.Log(System.Environment.Version);" and noticed that my version is 2.0.50727.1433.

In order to do what I wanted with named arguments I required C#4.0 version, and that is why I was getting this error.